# Karate Xml response filtering

Tags: karate

In my karate tests, i have Xml response like the following

```
<wkfcnf:workflow xmlns:wkfcnf="http://test.com/ri/configuration" name="test" status="ACTIVE" >
  <protocols>
    <protocol name="protocol1" uri="https://test/url/2"/>
    <protocol name="protocol2" uri="https://test/url/2"/>
  </protocols>
  <stages>
    <stage name="stage1" uri="https://stage/1"/>
   <stage name="stage2" uri="https://stage/1"/>
  </stages>
</wkfcnf:workflow>
```

I want to get the protocol Uri based on the protocol name.

Following is the code I have tried. But not working as expected.

```
* json prepProtocol = $response/workflow/protocols/protocol[(@.name='protocol1')]
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks
Subitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can be tricky. This worked for me:

```
* def prepProtocol = $response//protocol[@name='protocol2']/@uri
* match prepProtocol == 'https://test/url/2'
```

EDIT: if you need to use a variable:

```
* def name = 'protocol2'
* def prepProtocol = karate.xmlPath(response, "//protocol[@name='" + name + "']/@uri")
* match prepProtocol == 'https://test/url/2'
```

And you can get a little more elegant like this:

```
* def prepProtocol = karate.xmlPath(response, `//protocol[@name='${name}']/@uri`)
```

Comment: That's worked Peter.. thank you for that. Slight change was  $response//workflow//protocols//protocol[@name='protocol2']/@uri. What will be the syntax if i need to use a variable name instead of 'protocol2'

Comment: @Subitha made an edit to answer your question